# Proper form to call a method in Python?

Tags: python, class, inheritance

I was trying some examples on class inheritance and stumbled, on how to access the methods. In tutorials, the proper form is always Class().method(), however apparently, that's not the only solution.

```
class A():
    def open(self):
        print("class A method open")


class B():
    def open(self):
        print("class B method open")
    def close(self):
        print("class B method close")


class D(A, B):
    def end_reached(self):
        print("end reached")

## Why do both of the following lines work & produce the same output?
D().open()
D.open(1)
```

I expected the last line to give an error, however, the output is the same as from the line above. It did give an error on missing parameter, if the method gets called like D.open(), but giving it just any parameter works.

Is there any difference between the two lines?

Comment: This isn't an inheritance issue.  You would observe the same thing if you just used class `A` directly instead of `D`.  In `D().open()` you are making an ordinary method call from a class instance.  In `D.open(1)` you are calling an unbound method as a function and passing `1` for the first argument, i.e. `self`.  Have your `open` method print `self` and you'll see the difference.

Comment: @TomKarzes I think that deserves to be an answer (unless this is a dupe).

Answer (score 1):

The difference lays in the [descriptor protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html), specifically in [how descriptors provide Python's object-oriented features](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#functions-and-methods).

`open` is a class attribute of various classes; in each case, though, it has the type `function`. That type implements the descriptor protocol, via the definition of `function.__get__`, by returning either a `function` object or a `method` object, depending on whether `open` is accessed via the class itself or an instance of the class.

### Instance lookup

Given

```
d = D()
```

the attribute lookup `d.open` is equivalent to

```
type(d).__dict__['open'].__get__(d, D)
```

which returns a `method` which wraps the original function. When called, the method passes a reference to `d` and any of its own arguments to the wrapped function.

```
f = d.open  # The return value of __get__
f()         # open(d)
```

### Class lookup

The attribute lookup `D.open` is equivalent to

```
D.__dict__['open'].__get__(None, D)
```

which returns the function `open` itself.

```
f = D.open  # The return value of __get__
f(1)        # open(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not an inheritance problem.

As you can see in your method declaration, first argument is `self`.

`D()` just creates an object of class `D`. If you do anything on the object, that object is automatically passed as first argument.

However, when doing `D.open(1)` you don't invoke the method on the object, so the first argument in the method is first argument passed to it == your code assumes `self=1`. Because your methods behave like static methods (you don't use `self` inside them), you don't access `self`'s inside, so the code doesn't break.

But if your `open` method invoked anything from self (another method or a field),
then you would get an attribute error - because `int` object probably doesn't have a method like that.

---

Examples from build-in classes:

```
"aaa".split()
str.split("aaa")
```

They both behave the same.

`"aaa"` is of type `str`, so interpreted looks into class `str` for the method and automatically passes `"aaa"` as self. (Just like your `D()` is of type `D`. And `d=D()`, then `d.open()` will still know the type.)

The other one shows which class to ask for the method (`str`) but still needs an argument `self`. The way we define methods shows that "self" is really an argument as well, so we can just pass it.

Answer (score 0):

In order to learn about this, I have to go in depth about the properties of functions and methods.

Accessing a class field of a class via its instances checks if there are `__set__` and/or `__get__` methods. If they are, the call happens via `__get__`.

Functions work this way: if a function is a class field of a class (in short, methods), they are called via `function.__get__(object)(*args, **kwargs)`.

And here, we have a difference between Python 2 and Python 3:

- Python 2 unconditionally prepends the given `object` to the argumends and calls the underlying function with `function(object, *args, **kwargs)`. `object` gets assigned to `self` then, which by convention is the name of the first parameter of a method.
- Python 3 checks if the given `object` is an instance of the class as it should be. If it isn't, we get an exception. If it is, the call gets processed as above.

Example:

```
def outer_f(self):
    return "f called with", self

class C(object):
    f = outer_f
    def g(self):
        return "g called with", self

c = C()
print(outer_f(c))
print(C.f(c))
print(C.f.__get__(c)())
print(c.f())
print(C.g(c))
print(C.g.__get__(c)())
print(c.g())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class A():
    def open(self):
        print(self)
        print("class A method open")


class B():
    def open(self):
        print("class B method open")
    def close(self):
        print("class B method close")


class D(A, B):
    def end_reached(self):
        print("end reached")

## Why do both of the following lines work & produce the same output?
D().open() # Okay
D.open(1) # BAD
```

output

```
<__main__.D object at 0x0045FE90>
class A method open
1
class A method ope
```

You might want to look at a static method

```
class A():
    @staticmethod
    def open():
        print("open ran")


class D(A):
    def end_reached(self):
        print("end reached")


D.open() # Good
```

output

```
open ran
```